# Messaging.SingleEmailMessage with Template fails, but Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate() works?

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

I'm sending out a singleEmailMessage using a template.  The Messaging.SendEmailResult reports success and the email comes through, but the template portion of the email is empty.  (The WhatId is campaignMemberId cm.Id.)

```
emailTemplate eT = [SELECT Id from EmailTemplate WHERE Name like '%Invite_Interested_Vols%' LIMIT 1];
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage eMessage = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
eMessage.setTemplateId(eT.Id);
eMessage.setWhatId(cm.Id);
eMessage.setReplyTo(UserInfo.getUserEmail());
eMessage.setSenderDisplayName(UserInfo.getUserName());
Id TargetObjectId = cm.contactId == null ? cm.LeadId : cm.ContactId;
eMessage.setTargetObjectId(TargetObjectId);
messages.add(eMessage);
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages,true);
        if (results[0].success) {
            System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
        } else {
            System.debug('The email failed to send: '
                    + results[0].errors[0].message);
        }
```

The result is successful, but the email itself has no body.  The debug log shows no errors.

BUT (thanks to a hunch from Peter Churchill) if I use the Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate() method, the template is rendered and included in the email correctly.

```
emailTemplate eT = [SELECT Id from EmailTemplate WHERE Name like '%Invite_Interested_Vols%' LIMIT 1];
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Id TargetObjectId = cm.contactId == null ? cm.LeadId : cm.ContactId;
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emaildebug =
         Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(eT.Id,TargetObjectId,cm.Id);
emaildebug.saveAsActivity = false;
messages.add(emaildebug);
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages,true);
       if (results[0].success) {
           System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
       } else {
           System.debug('The email failed to send: '+ results[0].errors[0].message);
                }
```

Perhaps the different eMessage tags are conflicting with the WhatId in the first case???  Has anyone else run into this?

And a second question: Has anybody successfully used the new emailMessage object with a VisualForce template?  As far as I can tell, the Lightning templates don't allow the whatId to be a campaignmember, which is what this case needs.

Thanks for any insights,
Baird